# DAX Need Power Pivot Measure to be SUM of ALL Columns in Each Column. How to ignore column context

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a Pivot Table with Salespeople as columns. I have income measures that correctly show (in the rows) the income each of them produced. However, I would like to show everyone's income in each column on some of the measures.

The reason is I want them to be paid on some income items (row measures) on the total of all salespeople not on their individual production.

Is there a way to make a measure ignore the column context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DAX ALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634802.aspx)

Try to use `ALL` function and give your column as a parameter.

It will clear currently applied filters.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to put the measure in the ALL function instead of the Sales Person name column.